How to convert a surrealdb Response to User struct
Endpoint using rocket, making a query in table users
#[post("/", data="<user>")]
pub async fn create_user(user: Json<User>, db: &State<Database>) -> Custom<Value> {
    println!("Creating a new user");

    let response = json!(
        {
            "status": "success",
            "message": "User created successfully"
        }
    );


    let db_res = db.query(format!("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}')", user.name, user.email, user.password)).await;

    println!("{:?}", db_res);
    
    user_service::create_user();

    status::Custom(Status::Created, response)
}

db_res has the value:
Ok(Response { client: Surreal { router: OnceLock(Router { sender: Sender, last_id: 3, features: {LiveQueries} }), engine: PhantomData<surrealdb::api::engine::any::Any> }, results: {0: (Stats { execution_time: Some(233.411µs) }, Ok(Array(Array([Object(Object({"email": Strand(Strand("grizzy@email.com")), "id": Thing(Thing { tb: "users", id: String("j8g5v34qpq7mvs0bqdnf") }), "name": Strand(Strand("Grizzy")), "password": Strand(Strand("123"))}))]))))}, live_queries: {} })

How to extract only the user data from response and return a JSON on endpoint response?, like:
let user = // user data from db_res

let new_user = json!({
  id: user.id,
  name: user.name,
  email: user.email,
})


This simulates the input you mentioned plus wraps it in Rocket's Json wrapper so I think it should do the trick. The .take() method will always work if you have a matching type to deserialize it into.
    #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
    struct Users {
        email: String,
        name: String,
        password: String,
    }


    let res: Vec<Users> = db
        .query(
            "create users SET
            email = 'grizzy@email.com',
            name = 'Grizzy',
            password = '123';",
        )
        .await?.take(0)?;
    Json(res)

